# How can i pass msg.sender address from a factory(creator) contract to my main contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I am coding along with Stephen Grinders Udemy course, but it was released in 2017 so a lot of breaking changes. I am trying to have a (Factory) contract deploy another contract and pass it creators address (msg.sender) but i keep getting this error when i try to deploy with remix.

Edit: I am including the entire contact code. Please see if i have any errors

> "creation of Campaign errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.5.0) (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)".

```
contract Factory {
 address[] public campaigns;
 function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {
     Campaign deployed = new Campaign(minimum, address(msg.sender));
     campaigns.push(address(deployed));
 }
 function getCampaigns() public view returns(address[] memory){
     return campaigns;
 }
```

}

```
 contract Campaign {
 struct Request{
     string description;
     uint value;
     address payable recipient;
     bool complete;
     uint approvalCount;
     mapping (address => bool) approvals;
 }
 Request[] public requests;
 address public manager;
 uint public minimumContribution;
 mapping (address => bool) approvers;
//  mapping (uint => Request) requestList;
uint approversCount;
 uint index;

 modifier restricted(){
     require(msg.sender == manager);
     _;
 }

 constructor(uint minimum, address creator){
     manager = creator;
     minimumContribution = minimum;
     index = 0;
 }

 function contribute() public payable {
     require(msg.value >= minimumContribution);
     approvers[msg.sender] = true;
     approversCount++;
 }

 function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address payable recipient) 
    public restricted {
        uint requestLength = requests.length;
        requests.push();
        Request storage newRequest = requests[requestLength];
        newRequest.description = description;
        newRequest.value = value;
        newRequest.recipient = recipient;
        newRequest.complete = false;

 }

function approveRequests(uint id) public {
    require(approvers[msg.sender]);
    require(!requests[id].approvals[msg.sender]);
    requests[id].approvalCount++;
    requests[id].approvals[msg.sender] = true;

}

function finalizeRequest(uint id) public restricted {
    require(!requests[id].complete);
    require(requests[id].approvalCount > (approversCount / 2));
    requests[id].complete = true;
    requests[id].recipient.transfer(requests[id].value);
}
```

}

Comment: it works for me with remix and solidity compiler version 0.8.11.
in your second contract is "manager" an address?

Comment: Yes, it  is an address.

Comment: Majd TL i have included my entire contract code. Please see if I have any errors

Comment: What compiler version are you using?
Tested your code with 0.8.10 and it's ok

Comment: I just tried it again with "pragma solidity 0.8.10;" same error

Comment: the complete contract works for me 2 with remix, try other browser